# HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host return incorrect value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf-ria-services

My web url is www.test.com and I try to get this URL by `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host`  but it return IP Address instead of that URL. I check by fiddler and it Host is also IP Address. I want to know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use below to fetch url from code:

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Trim();
```

Comment: It's return IP address, not sure why.

Comment: what is your url in the address bar ?

Comment: www.test.com, I set www.test.com to redirect to localhost in host file.

Comment: Please remove redirect to localhost and then check the url ? Cause is redirect, you will get localhost in the url property.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the IP since you are trying to use the `Host property of the URL`. You should see the `AbsoluteUri property of URL` to get complete URL Info. e.g.

```
String url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

Comment: It also return IP address, not actual URL in address bar. I'm not sure do I need to configure something in IIS or not?

Comment: www.test.com, I set www.test.com to redirect to localhost in host file.

Comment: I see localhost from URL property.

Comment: then there must be your Server IIS configuration issue

Comment: where can I configure IIS to get web address not ip address?